# gnome-terminal / mate-terminal don't save history on ~/.bash_history

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, mate

Two days ago I was using my computer as usual, when I noticed that the commands I used in mate-terminal were not saved in the history. I tried installing `gnome-terminal`. But it does the same. I was researching about it, and I found that it could be a problem with permissions on `~./bash_history` but I checked them and they are good. I don't think it's a problem with BASH because I tried using `XTerm` and it does write to the file.

Edit:
This is the output for the suggested commands:

mate-terminal:

```
mike@mikeUBU:~$ echo "$HISTFILE"
/home/mike/.bash_history

mike@mikeUBU:~$ ls -l ~/.bash_history
-rw------- 1 mike mike 288 Jul 30 01:59 /home/mike/.bash_history

mike@mikeUBU:~$ history | wc
     13      57     431

mike@mikeUBU:~$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
2000

mike@mikeUBU:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3647 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

XTerm:

```
mike@mikeUBU:~$ echo "$HISTFILE"
/home/mike/.bash_history

mike@mikeUBU:~$ ls -l ~/.bash_history
-rw------- 1 mike mike 288 Jul 30 01:59 /home/mike/.bash_history

mike@mikeUBU:~$ history | wc
     15      65     480

mike@mikeUBU:~$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
2000

mike@mikeUBU:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3850 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

Comment: Whats the output of `echo "$HISTFILE"` ?

Comment: @heemayl ok, your comment is better =)

Comment: @A.B. Yeah..this should give us some idea..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of these commands: `ls -l ~/.bash_history`; `history | wc`; `echo $HISTFILESIZE`; `echo $HISTFILE`; `ps -p $$` (run it in `mate` or `gnome` terminal and then also on `xterm`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already edited the question with the output from the commands. Still, only those made with XTerm were saved.

Comment: Due to an unknown reason the '~/.bash_history' file of my User 'user' belongs to 'root' at my system: 'ls -la ~/.bash_history' results in '-rw------- 1 root root 191 Mai 27 19:40 /home/user/.bash_history'. After removing the file, the problem was gone!

Answer (score 1):

I could not get to solve this problem. My solution was to reinstall Ubuntu MATE, but only the system. I have my home folder in another partition. I chose the installation method that kept my files. Also some apps were kept. After reinstalling, the problem was gone.

Comment: Due to an unknown reason the '~/.bash_history' file of my User 'user' belongs to 'root' at my system: 'ls -la  ~/.bash_history' results in '-rw------- 1 root root 191 Mai 27 19:40 /home/user/.bash_history'. After removing the file, the problem was gone!

Answer (score 0):

What are the contents of the history file? Do the contents change? Is it overwriting rather than appending?

How you can tell, is to give the `history` command, then give some other commands, `date` `echo $PWD` `which man` whatever, then run the history command. If there is any change, then the bash history file is likely being over written, rather than appended to. If its always the same, as in it wrote some command history a while ago, and hasn't changed since.... then IDK, but it would be nifty to know.

Anyhow, I would bet the solution lies some place in your .bashrc file, where a variety of settings for dealing with history are kept.

Here are some of the history settings from my .bashrc file:

```
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

the shopt built-in says If set, the history list is appended to the file named by the value of the HISTFILE variable when the shell exits, rather than overwriting the file.

You might search down to the bottom of your .bashrc if there are differing functions or parameters for the history command, the ones at the end of the file will take effect.

if your .bashrc file looks like this, or if you can post further details, I will be happy to look into this further this evening.
I am a bit suprized that xterm doesn't have a separate history log.
If you're ok with doing so, posting your .bashrc file may be helpful.